# Is PayPal ExpressCheckout deprecated?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm new on PayPal SDK, and have to integrate a payment gateway; I use PHP, and reading the documentation about the PayPal PHP SDK on GitHub says that the Merchant SDK is deprecated, in order to use the new Rest API SDK.

But, my question is: In Rest API SDK there is not any reference to Express Checkout, it have Payment Flow. So, ExpressCheckout is deprecated?

Sorry if I'm loss about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Merchant SDK is deprecated; however, Express Checkout is not. The PayPal payment of the REST API leverages Express Checkout.

Edit: The deprecation note has been removed from the Merchant SDKs.

Comment: I would step in here and say no, it's not deprecated.  REST is simply a new method of doing it.  The Classic API, though, is still very much in play and is even continuing to see updates to it.  It's also a lot more mature and has lots more features tied into it than PayPal payments with REST has.  I still prefer the Classic API for now, personally.

Comment: I've noticed that PayPal have been through all of the repositories (PHP, .NET, Ruby) and [removed the deprecated message](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/commit/dff38d37a764a673bc896bcd1e7ce48b64db4ce8) that they had on the README from each.

Answer (score 3):

to be concise PayPal Express Checkout is called 'PayPal Payment' when using REST APIs. [Please go here for REST API for a PayPal Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) and  [Here is a Reference Guide as well](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/). Hope this helps!